# iPhone X: UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-autolayout

I have constraint errors regarding the tableviewcell height only on iPhone X. All other devices have no constraint errors.

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000297160 UIImageView:0x7fe64585cfe0.height == 33   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c0002972f0 V:|-(5)-[UIImageView:0x7fe64585cfe0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe64585cdf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000297390 V:[UIImageView:0x7fe64585cfe0]-(5.5)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe64585cdf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60c000297840 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe64585cdf0.height == 43.6667   (active)>"
)
```

Any idea what might cause this?

Update - I solved it by changing priority of one constraint to 750, but it is unclear why this is causing problems only on iPhone X.

Comment: Using [wtfautolayout](http://wtfautolayout.com) it seems there is a conflict between your constraints and the constraint that the table view has added to set its height.